# In Conky, how do I convert from Unix time to hours and minutes? (HH:MM)

Tags: unix-timestamp, conky

Given a Unixtime such as 1551996855 (Thu, 07 Mar 2019 22:14:15 +0000), how can convert and extract just HH:MM, (22:14)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `date` for the conversion and specify `+%H:%M` as the format:

```
date -d @$"1551996855" +%H:%M
```

- note: the option to use with `date` will be different than `-d` if you are not on a Linux system (which uses `date` from GNU coreutils).. so YMMV